# Cramér's theorem - Legendre transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, large-deviation-theory

Consider $X_1, X_2,\dots $ i.i.d. random variables that are geometrically distributed with parameter $\frac 1 2$.
With the moment generating function of $X_1$ (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)) one gets
$$
\Lambda(t) = \log E[e^{tX_1}] = \log \frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}=-\log(2) +  t-\log\left(1-\frac 1 2 e^t\right).
$$
I'd like to know what the rate function $I(\cdot)$ is though. In my textbook, I have this formula
$$
I(x)=\Lambda^*(x) = \sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\left\{ tx - \Lambda(t) \right\} 
=
\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\left\{ tx +\log(2) -  t+\log\left(1-\frac 1 2 e^t\right) \right\}. 
$$
The solution is supposed to be (but have not found a way to get there):
$$
I(x)=x\log x-(1+x) \log\left( \frac{1+x}{2} \right).
$$
If you could provide one or two hints, I'd be really glad!

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you few steps

1. Show that $\Lambda(t)$ is convex and therefore $tx-\Lambda(t)$ is concave. Thus there will be just one maximum of $tx-\Lambda(t)$.
2. Now differentiate $tx-\Lambda(t)$ with respect to $t$ and express $e^t$ in terms of $x$.

Response to the comment: your calculation is correct but the confusion occurred because of the definition of geometric distribution that you have used. Use the distribution that has support $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and probability mass function $p_k$, where
$$
p_k = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \,\text{  for  }\,k=0,1,\ldots.
$$
Let me know if you can complete it from here.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

1. We have 
$$ 
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \Lambda(t) = \frac{2e^t}{(2-e^t)^2} \geq 0.
 $$
2. Here, we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left( tx - \Lambda(t)\right) = \frac{e^t}{2-e^t}+x-1. 
$$
With this, we get
$$
e^t = \frac{2(1-x)}{2-x}.
$$
Now, have I done something wrong? How does this help me?

Comment: Then plug this in $tx-\Lambda(t)$ to get $I(x)$.

Comment: That's what I tried, but didn't get the right answer. Also double-checked with WolframAlpha. Are you sure this works?

Comment: @simon I have edited the answer to address the issue. Best.